# naudio Midi input - filter e.MidiEvent to just data2 parameter?

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

Writing an app that takes MIDI input using naudio. Managed to get midi input going and outputting fine to the console, but to use the data I need to be able to isolate parts of the data. My code is

```
    void midiIn_MessageReceived(object sender, MidiInMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.MidiEvent);
    }
```

which writes the following line to the console.

```
0 ControlChange Ch: 1 Controller 48 Value 51
```

This is fine but how do I only get data2 (the value) to then pass on to something? I could do something awful like slice it up as a string but this is probably not the way forward...

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the MIDI message from the message information:

```
void midiIn_MessageReceived(object sender, MidiInMessageEventArgs e)
{
    MidiEvent me = e.MidiEvent;
```

Then you have to check for the correct message type:

```
    ControlChangeEvent cce = me as ControlChangeEvent;
    if (cce != null) {
```

And handle it:

```
        Console.WriteLine(cce.ControllerValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yaaas! Thats the one. Cheers :)